# Memoized components gets their children re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react 16.6 with material UI and I'm having a real bad time trying to avoid unnecessary re-renderings. I tried almost everything I can think about and the children components of material ui gets re-rendered on every user interaction. It does not matter that propertis are literally the same, they gets re-rendered.

I tried to use memo froom react,and the root component gets memoized and avoids unnecessary re-renderings, but even with that the child components are being detected as re-rendered by all the react tools that I tried (react dev tools and why did you update package)

Here is a simple snippet:

```
import React, { PureComponent, memo } from 'react';

import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemSecondaryAction from '@material-ui/core/ListItemSecondaryAction';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';

const rowText = ({ title, artist }) =>
  console.log('Row text render') || (
    <ListItemText primary={title} secondary={artist} />
  );

const RowText = memo(rowText);

const row = ({ selected, song, onSelect, favorite, LikeButton }) =>
  console.log('Row rendered') || (
    <ListItem
      button
      selected={selected === song.title}
      onClick={() => onSelect(song.title)}
    >
      {selected === song.title && <PlayArrowIcon color="primary" />}
      <RowText {...song} />
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <LikeButton liked={favorite} title={song.title} />
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
  );

row.displayName = 'Row';

const Row = memo(row);
```

That logs to the console just once `Row rendered` `Row text render`, But the rest of the items like ListItemSecondaryAction ListItemt and ListItemText are reported to be re-rendered. How is this possible ? I expected memoize to return the exact same object, hende avoiding re-rendrings

Edit: I tried the more radical solution that I can think of:

```
class Row extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    return false;
  };
```

Even with that I get messages of avoidable re-rendering for all the children of the component

Even on the simplest component (with just one MUI component) and a radical don't udpate me on any case, I get unnecessary re renders

```
class RowText extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
    return false;
  };

  render() {
    const { title, artist } = this.props;
    return <ListItemText primary={title} secondary={artist} />;
  }
}
```

This must be some kind of bug on material ui

**EDIT**

This only happens for ListItem component and their children, so it must be some kind of bug on them. I tried the same techniques with other components and the children does not get re-rendered if they should not.

Comment: Are you changing the data passed to your list? `ListItem` is wrapped in a higher-order component to access context from the List ancestor, it might be getting force updated outside your code.

Comment: At this point I think I better include the entire code. I am not passing anything to the list ancestor. This is somewhat curious because while an spinner on another component is running the state of this one stills re-rendering, so material components should be somewhat connected. Maybe through withStyles ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm encountering the same problem now with a couple different MUI components...

Comment: I just stopped trying, sorry. But Ithink it has to do with context providers, which go directly to MUI components, bypassing parents.